# Construct a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p : [0,+\infty) \longrightarrow (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function which satisfies the following condition :
$$\lim_{x\longrightarrow +\infty} \sqrt{x} p(x) = 0.$$

Does there exist a function $f: [0,+\infty) \longrightarrow (0,+\infty)$ such that

- $\dfrac{1}{f}$ is bounded;
- $\dfrac{f(x)}{p(x)}\in L^1(0,+\infty)$.

Certainly, we can choose a specific function $p$ satisfying the previous condition to prove the existence of $f$.

Comment: Isaac, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I made a mistake. It is a quotion and not a product.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the product $fp$ of the two functions by $f \times p$.

If we have that $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded we get $|f|\geq \epsilon$ for an $\epsilon>0$.

It follows that $\|fp\|_{L^1}\geq \epsilon\|p\|_{L^1}$.

Now $p(x):=(x+1)^{-0.6}$ satisfies the assumption but is not in $L^1$. So $fp$ is not in $L^1$ aswell.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.